# Why does this simple SQL query from SQL Server 2000 have different results in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

Using MS SQL 2000 it was possible to have a query such as:

```
SELECT (Code + ' = ' + EdiNumber + ',') AS MyResult FROM tblCountry
```

Which would give you a  list of results like:

```
MyResult
========
ZW = 263,
ZA = 27,
...
```

However, in MS SQL 2008 that query returns:

```
-1 records affected
```

Does anyone know a) Why? and b) How to get the SQL 2000 result from SQL 2008?

**UPDATE**

Im just using a standard ASP.NET connection string to connect to the database using a console to post the query:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True; Database=MyDB
```

Comment: Have you some security restrictions? Try to execute query from 'sa'

Comment: What tool are you using to execute this query?

Comment: `-1 records affected` is database output (metadata), not your query result. You're probably looking in the wrong window in whatever tool you're running from..

Comment: @StevieG: When I run a `SELECT Code FROM tblCountry` the results are shown fine

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

`-1 records affected` was clearly the non-privileged result because all that was actually happening was an error in the query whilst trying to concatenate a `string` (Code) and an `int` (EdiNumber)

The correct query should have been:

```
SELECT (Code + ' = ' + CAST(EdiNumber AS VARCHAR) + ',') as MyResult FROM tblCountry
```

Once I got that correct, the query worked fine from the original console.

Comment: Your code seems to bury exception messages. You don't need any particular privileges to see those.